# Do I need to synchronize both method and object

Tags: java, synchronization

So I have the following list which is accessed from multiple threads:

`ArrayList<String> listOfString = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());`

I know that when I iterate through the list I have to synchronize like so:

```
synchronized(listOfString)
{
    for(String s : listOfString) System.out.println(s);

    listOfString.clear();
}
```

What about if I want to remove something, do I do this:

```
public void removeString(String s)
{
    listOfString.remove(s);
}
```

or this:

```
public synchronized void removeString(String s)
{
    listOfString.remove(s);
}
```

Comment: Personally, if I'm going to be iterating through the `List` somewhere ... I don't bother with the `Collections.synchronizedList()` call and simply synchronize on the `List` for *all* operations. This is more explicit for the next person who reads/touches the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, the list is already synchronized, so your `removeString` method does not need to be `synchronized` too.

Note however that if one of your methods contains a non-atomic operation (say you want to check if your list contains something then modify the list accordingly), you might need to add another layer of synchronization.

Finally, you don't seem to have noticed that this method:

```
public synchronized void removeString(String s)
```

synchronizes on a different lock (it synchronizes on `this`). So back to the example I gave above, you would write it:

```
public void someMethod() {
    synchronized(listOfString) { //use the same lock!
        if(listOfString.size() == 123) {
            listOfString.add("lucky day");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aw, I was typing that second part. Oh well, +1

Comment: +1, synchronizedList only takes care of making the list itself thread safe, but in the question there is already a multi-part operation (iterate and clear) which is probably meant to be atomic.